# timedatectl Failed to query server

Tags: 14.04, networking, time, ntp

I am working on a Business Gateway and I have a problem with the TimeZone not working.
Earlier, the output of timedatectl used to give the below output

```
root@BusinessGateway:/# timedatectl
Warning: Ignoring the TZ variable. Reading the system's time zone setting only.
Local time: Fri 2017-09-08 07:05:21 UTC
Universal time: Fri 2017-09-08 07:05:21 UTC
RTC time: n/a
Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
RTC in local TZ: no
DST active: n/a
```

After rebase to a new firmware the TimeZone stopped working and the output of timedatectl gives the below output

```
root@cga4131:~# timedatectl
Failed to query server: Operation not permitted
```

What could've possibly gone wrong? Any inputs would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Active Directory / Centrify, you can try to reboot the server.  That is what they suggested us to do and it worked for us.  However, it is unclear what the underlying cause is to me, nor is it very satisfying if it is a shared server where you can't just reboot it willy-nilly.